# How to update psql table using php?

Tags: php, sql-update, psql

**What I want?** 
I want to update database table variables using `PHP`

**My query:**

```
UPDATE users SET access_token = ‘V3VIANGT2qiOYVPOcDpoOBW7gX468YnhYCRa85Htn3tSWhFg9xqU8vZCCTMBGEUB056pEdA0dQ3Hp3pdTL08HOTI3P6pdeP3w3wNQPvgZDZDEAALMor5nBJgBABtXay2JCU7lN102L6ZCq58adeoPPwYoQHqvAvuWZCz6H8NtoBool’;
```

(made up token string)

**Result:**

`UPDATE error : column does not exist`

```
ERROR:  column "‘V3VIANGT2qiOYVPOcDpoOBW7gX468YnhYCRa85Ht" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE users SET access_token = ‘V3VIANGT2qiOYVPOcDpoOBW7gX46...
```

Is this an issue with max string length?

Because the current value in the database is the same length. I just didn't insert it through sql commands but rather through `php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using a single quote and not a back quote. (If you're using a US keyboard, single quote is above the double quotes, the backquote is next to the one)

Comment: I tried both actually and got the same error either way

Comment: What happens when you run update users set access_token = 'hello'

Comment: I receive the same error. So it isn't a string length issue.

Comment: And you're using psql from the command line to run this update command? Windows/Linux/OS X?

Comment: Yes. It turns out it was the single quote issue you first mentioned. I was copying and pasting the command directly of psql docs, and then after editing it i was pasting it into the terminal. Somehow my quote type converted. The solution was to copy from the documentation, paste directly into the terminal, and edit the query there.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are updating on database remember we need to specify two column headings.

Imagine table `user` is like this:

```
╭───╥───────────┬───────┬────────────────╮
│   ║  name     │  id   │ access_token   │
╞═══╬═══════════╪═══════╪════════════════╡
│ 1 ║ user_1    │ 3453  │ V3VIANGT2qiO   │
│ 2 ║ user_2    │ 5435  │ YI$97jwkiw98   │
│ 3 ║ user_3    │ 5432  │ HJU2kasjk2kk   │
└───╨───────────┴───────┴────────────────┘
```

`UPDATE user SET access_token='OImjsw23kmn43' WHERE name='user_1';`

Other wise database will not understand which `access_token` variable to update.